# Can I use a Arduino Mega Clone with a RAMPS 1.4 shield?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, ramps-1.4, arduino-mega-2650, arduino

I'm trying to build my own 3D-printer and I'm considering using a RAMPS 1.4 shield on an Arduino Mega 2560 as the controller. I could save $30-40 by using a clone Arduino Mega (not the official one) that uses the ATMega 256. Would the RAMPS 1.4 still work with this board?

Comment: RAMPS is completely obsolete and will not support modern drivers. Consider something like a SKR 2 or SKR Mini e3 board

Answer (score 1):

Yes a clone of the Arduino Mega will work with a RAMPS 1.4 shield. I've used these combinations in the past.

---

However, it is advised to buy a dedicated printer controller board, preferably a 32-bit micro processor board, these have more memory so you will less likely run into too less memory for specific functions of the printer firmware (unless you'll be using Klipper, but that requires a RaspberyyPi, so not a cheap solution).